# Groupby by One column and get sum of values as columns based on months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which contains items and their quantiy brought on a certain date. For eg.

```
date         Item     qty
2016-01-04    Rice     3
2016-01-04    Ball     3
2016-01-10    Rice     5
2016-02-02    Coffee  10
2016-02-06    Rice     3
 .....         ...    ..
```

The data is for 2 years, 2016 to  May,2018.

I want to know how much was every item sold across monthwise, from Jan 2016 to May 2018. And Plot a Line Graph for it(x axis - months, y - quantities of products)

For that i thought of creating a dataframe in this format:

```
Date    Rice   Coffee   Ball
Jan 16   8       0       3
Feb 16   10      17      5
 ....    ...    ...      ...
May 18   11      9       12
```

How can i get the data in this format??

One option i thought was 
  `df.groupby([df.date.dt.year.rename('year'),df.date.dt.month.rename('month')]).agg({'qty':np.sum}).reset_index()`

But it is not working, Is there a better way to get the results in the above format, or any better way to store the results so that it will be convinient to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want like this,

```
df= df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month),'Item']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
df.columns=df.columns.droplevel()
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

O/P
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom [format of datetimes](http://strftime.org/) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby([df.date.dt.strftime('%b %y'), 'Item'])['qty'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

If order of datetimes is important use `ordered categoricals`:

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
dates = df.date.dt.strftime('%b %y')
dates = pd.Categorical(dates, ordered=True, categories=dates.unique())
df1 = df.groupby([dates, 'Item'])['qty'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
dates = df.date.dt.strftime('%b %y')
df1 = df.groupby([dates, 'Item'])['qty'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(dates.unique())
```

---

```
print (df1)
Item    Ball  Coffee  Rice
Jan 16     3       0     8
Feb 16     0      10     3
```

Last plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df1.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
>>> df
        date    Item  qty
0 2016-01-04    Rice    3
1 2016-01-04    Ball    3
2 2016-01-10    Rice    5
3 2016-02-02  Coffee   10
4 2016-02-06    Rice    3
```

with

```
>>> df.dtypes
date    datetime64[ns]
Item            object
qty              int64
dtype: object
```

you can do

```
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
>>> offset = MonthEnd()
>>> 
>>> df.set_index('date').groupby([offset.rollforward, 'Item']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
            qty            
Item       Ball Coffee Rice
2016-01-31    3      0    8
2016-02-29    0     10    3
```

I'd keep the index like this because there are usable dates in there. If you really must convert these to strings like `'Jan 16'`, you can do so with:

```
>>> result = df.set_index('date').groupby([offset.rollforward, 'Item']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
>>> result.index = result.index.map(lambda d: d.strftime('%b %y'))
>>> result
        qty            
Item   Ball Coffee Rice
Jan 16    3      0    8
Feb 16    0     10    3
```